# How to access data from child component? Angular2

Tags: angular, components, parent-child

I have created component named `app-inline-edit` and it is supposed to be used like this:

```
<app-inline-edit (onSave)="saveEditCheck($event)">
    <app-select formControlName="CurrentCar" [options]="carOptions"></app-select>
</app-inline-edit>
```

By default it should show value under "CurrentCar" as plain string with pencil icon next to it. If user clicks on string or icon it should render "app-select" component with two icons: one for saving changes, the other for discarding them.

EDIT:
Child of `app-inline-edit` does not always be the `app-select`, it can be also different component.
This is the template I have:

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="editing">
    <div #inlineEditControl class="inline-edit-input">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" (click)="save()"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" (click)="discard()"></i>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!editing">
    <div title="Click to edit" (focus)="edit(value);" tabindex="0" class="inline-edit">
        {{value}}&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" (click)="edit(value)"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to access it via

```
@ViewChild('inlineEditControl') inlineEditControl: ElementRef;
```

But when `editing` is `false` `inlineEditControl` is `undefined`.
The problem I've run into is. How can I access selected value (CurrentCar) attached to "app-select" if by default select is not rendered? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `@ViewChild` to that

In your component

```
@ViewChild<AppSelectComponent> appSelectComponent: AppSelectComponent;

this.appSelectComponent.options /////////////// have it here


<app-select formControlName="CurrentCar" [options]="carOptions"></app-select>
```

Comment: It could be the solution if Child would be always the same component. Unfortunately it is not my case. Forgot to mention this, sorry. I've added more details in post.

Comment: Can u create a plunker??